# Activity with Listview does not show the items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have the activity "VerSolicitudesPendientesActivity.java" which load when i select one item of main´s menu.
This activity contains a listview which does not shows the list, but yes the TextView.
This is the activity:

```
public class VerSolicitudesPendientesActivity extends Activity {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_solicitudes);
    System.out.println("OncreateSolicitudes");
    System.out.println("Contenido enlazado: Solicitudes.");
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    System.out.println("Extras obtenidos");

    String usuario= bundle.getString("usuario");
    System.out.println("Usuario que revisa solicitudes: "+ usuario);

    cargaSolicitudes(usuario);
    System.out.println("Accediendo a solicitudes");


}
public void cargaSolicitudes(String usuario){
    System.out.println("Llegamos a carga solicitudes.");
    ListView lista= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaSolicitudes);
    //System.out.println("Lista obtenida del xml.");

    ArrayList<Solicitante> arraySolicitudes= new ArrayList<Solicitante>();
    Solicitante solicitante;
    //System.out.println("Antes de cargar solicitudes (Solicitantes)");

    //Introduccion de datos en el array. Aqui es donde se deben cargar los datos de la BB.DD
    solicitante= new Solicitante("Pablo","zz@zz",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fotoamigo));
    arraySolicitudes.add(solicitante);
    //System.out.println("Solicitante 1 cargado "+ solicitante.nombreSolicitante);

    solicitante= new Solicitante("Jon","zz@yy",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fotoamigo2));
    arraySolicitudes.add(solicitante);
    //System.out.println("Solicitante 2 cargado "+ solicitante.nombreSolicitante);

    System.out.println("Solicitudes cargadas en adapter");

    // Creamos el adapter
    SolicitudesAdapter adapter= new SolicitudesAdapter(this,arraySolicitudes,getBaseContext());
    // Una vez hecha la conexión pasamos los datos.
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void aceptaSolicitud(View v){
    Solicitante solicitante= (Solicitante) v.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Solicitud de "+solicitante+" ha sido aceptada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
public void rechazaSolicitud(View v){
    Solicitante solicitante= (Solicitante) v.getTag();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Solicitud de "+solicitante+" ha sido rechazada.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

This is my custom adapter:

```
public class SolicitudesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

protected Activity activity;
protected ArrayList<Solicitante> solicitantes;
protected Context mContext;
public SolicitudesAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Solicitante> solicitantes,Context context){
    this.activity= activity;
    this.solicitantes= solicitantes;
    this.mContext=context;
}
public Context getmContext() {
    return mContext;
}
public void setmContext(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
@SuppressLint({ "ViewHolder", "InflateParams" })
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v= inf.inflate(R.layout.lista_solicitudes,null);
    //Asociar el layout de la lista que hemos creado.
    //Definimos un objeto a partir del array, vamos a cargar el contenido
    //de ese objeto en el view de la lista.
    System.out.println("Dentro del adapter");

    Solicitante soli= solicitantes.get(position);
        //Cargamos la fotografía del amigo.
        ImageView foto= (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imagenSolicitud);
        foto.setImageDrawable(soli.getFoto());
        System.out.println("Imagen botonAmigo cargada en la view");
        //Cargamos el nombre del evento
        TextView nombre= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textoSolicitud);
        String cadena =soli.getNombreSolicitante()+" quiere ser tu amigo.";
        nombre.setText(cadena);
        Button botonAcepta= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.botonAceptaSolicitud);
        botonAcepta.setTag(soli);
        Button botonRechaza= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.botonRechazaSolicitud);
        botonRechaza.setTag(soli);
        System.out.println("Hemos adaptado a "+ soli.nombreSolicitante);


    return v;
}
```

This is the xml contains the listview and textview for show in the activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pruebaTexto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prueba de que se carga el contenido de la actividad." />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaSolicitudes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:listitem="@layout/solicitudlist" >
</ListView>
```

In graphic mode of this xml file i can see the list correctly below the TextView.
And finally, this is the item of the list.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/borde_naranja" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textoSolicitud"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/fraseSolicitud" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagenSolicitud"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textoSolicitud"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fotoamigo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonAceptaSolicitud"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textoSolicitud"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_rellenonaranja"
    android:onClick="aceptaSolicitud"
    android:text="@string/aceptar"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonRechazaSolicitud"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/botonAceptaSolicitud"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/botonAceptaSolicitud"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textoSolicitud"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/borde_rellenonaranja"
    android:onClick="rechazaSolicitud"
    android:text="@string/rechazar"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

I have not any compilation error. When the activity starts i can see the textView but no the listView. The program is re-re-re-revised but i dont know which can be the problem. I hope find help here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning wrong count of the `ArrayList` in the adapter. This count is used to render the views.

In your adapter change this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return solicitantes.size();
}
```

Comment: The answer from @Rohit5k2 is absolutely correct. Why has someone down voted this?!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This worked!. Now i have another problem, inside the adapter the program stops caused by Null PointerException in when i load the photo: foto.setImageDrawable(soli.getFoto()); and the item is inizialized correctly in the activity.

Comment: I would suggest you to change the signature of `Solicitante` class  to `<String, String, int>` and the use this `solicitante= new Solicitante("Jon","zz@yy",R.drawable.fotoamigo2);`. Rest everything looks good.

Comment: Thanks again.The problem is that nullpointer happens with all "set"s of the adapter. The ImageView (photo), the name, buttons... all shows null pointerexceptions.. I have another adapters and they works well :(

Comment: Are you using correct layout in `getView()`. Is `R.layout.lista_solicitudes` correct?

Comment: I love you mate.... No words to be grateful for this help. In one of my tries i changed the item layout for compleate layout... Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Still I got 2 downvotes for the answer. I am damn sure no one can say my answer was wrong. It should be mandatory to leave a comment if you downvote any answer.

Comment: Yes, i dont understand why people votes for you negatively... I haven´t enough reputation for vote your answer positively.

Comment: No worries. There are some people who can't answer but just downvote.  :D